# jQuery- Exclude from hover out

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my code, hovering over an image creates a new link with a class of '.pin_it' on top of that image. If the user moves the mouse away from the image, the .pin_it should hide. However, if they move the mouse over the new .pin_it, it should stay visible.

I've got this all working. The problem is that after they have moused over .pin_it, moving outside the image should hide .pin_it, but it doesn't. Then, if you hover back in, it will add ANOTHER .pin_it, but will not respect the mouse-out behavior at all any more.

What am I doing wrong?

JS Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/rKZK5/2/

Code:

```
$('img').hover(
function() {
  var imgWidth = $(this).width();
  var imgPosition = $(this).offset();
  if(imgWidth > 300) {
      $('body').append('<a href="#" class="pin_it">Pin It</a>');
      $('.pin_it').css(imgPosition);
  }
  else {
      // Do Nothing
  }
}, function() {
  var isHovered = $('.pin_it').is(":hover");

  if (isHovered == true) {
      //Do nothing
  } else {
    $('.pin_it').remove();       
  }
});
```

Comment: Update- I've got it mostly fixed. Only issue now is that if you mouse over the "Pin it" button, and then off to the left side without touching the image, it stays visible instead of hiding. http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/rKZK5/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reconsider your markup, by:

- adding a wrapper for your image and inserting your pin button inside it and setting it not visible
- when you hover the wrapper show the button
- when you leave the wrapper hide the button

Code:

```
$('#imgWrapper').hover(

function () {
    var imgWidth = $(this).width();
    var imgPosition = $(this).offset();
    if (imgWidth > 300) {
        $('.pin_it').css(imgPosition).show();
    } else {
        //
    }
}, function () {
    $('.pin_it').hide();
});
```

You'll have no problems with heavy DOM manipulation from add/remove elements and the code looks simple.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/fzM7k/

Comment: Definitely agree, although I'm writing this little script to be placed on a website that I don't control the markup. The rules are that it should automatically apply to any image larger than 300px.

Comment: In domready event you can wrap all images with a div and insert the button, I think you can handle the problem in this way

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it's how it SHOULD be done. Due to my circumstance, I'm going to handle it differently. I've gotten my code to mostly work now: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/rKZK5/4/